# Python / PyGame: Get window size

Tags: python, resize, window, pygame, updates

I've got a program / game with a resizable window. But how do I refresh my xSize and ySize variables, when my window gets resized? I need that in order to resize my surface etc.
If you don't get the sense of my question, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer myself:

```
if event.type == VIDEORESIZE:
            xSize = event.dict['size'][0]
            xSize = event.dict['size'][1]
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode((xSize, ySize), HWSURFACE|DOUBLEBUF|RESIZABLE)
```

But somehow the variables are right, but the drawings on my window don't change in size. (They are told to fit at the variables, and they're updated all the time..)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this:

```
if event.type == VIDEORESIZE:
    xSize = event.dict['size'][0]
    ySize = event.dict['size'][1]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((xSize, ySize), HWSURFACE|DOUBLEBUF|RESIZABLE
```

The second one should be ySize not xSize